# In ASOIAF books, how many dragons are there in present time?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Ever since *Game of Thrones* has shown 4 dragons in the intro, the internet is losing its mind, especially after the

> death of one dragon

in last episode.

[image: Intro image showing 4 dragons]

One fan theory says that Drogon is actually a female which layed multiple eggs when she disappeared in the season 5.

Another fan theory which is very famous says that Daenerys herself can transform into a dragon to become real mother of dragon.

I am interested to know what books say about it. In books, how many dragons are there in present day (not talking about legends)?

Comment: The fourth dragon, the large one, most probably refers to Daenerys. She's a dragon (in the same sens that the Starks are wolves and the Lannisters are lions: it's their sigil; and in addition dragons and Targaryens are historically connected) and brought the other three dragons to life.

Answer (score 16):

At May 12, 2019
On the Books, three dragons **Drogon**, **Rhaegal** and **Viserion** are alive. Rumor is there are more dragons at east.

On the TV show
Before Game of Thrones s08e05

Just one dragon alive in Westeros *he* is named '**Drogon**' after Khal Drogo.

> '**Viserion**', was killed by the Night King.
> '**Rhaegal**', was killed by Euron Greyjoy.

Well 'Mother of Dragon' is alive as well.

Answer (score 6):

The show is way ahead of the books, which end with the events covered in season 5. At that point, as in the show, Daenerys is still in Meereen and her three dragons are all alive.

Until she hatched the eggs, dragons were extinct as far as the world knew.

Answer (score 4):

The last dragon died during the reign of Aegon III, 'The Dragonbane'.

In the show there is only one remaining dragon whose name is "Drogon". It's not confirmed whether he reproduced or not.

In the books, there are three dragons confirmed to be alive i.e. Drogon, Rhaegal and Viserion. There is also speculation of more dragons being alive in the Shadowlands and further east.